# NSOperation suspended after sleep mode

Tags: objective-c, macos, amazon-s3, sleep, nsoperation

I am using S3uploader OSx sdk (I modified the IOS sdk) for uploading files in my app. For what ever files (one file or a chunk of files) I upload, am creating an NSOperation. This operation will invoke the S3uploader sdk to upload the files. It's all working fine when my system is awake. But if I go to sleep mode and come back, the NSOperation seems to be hanged. It's not continuing it's operations. I debugged and found that it's hanged in

**-(S3UploadPartResponse *)uploadPart:(S3UploadPartRequest *)uploadPartRequest;**

function. Maybe when I went to sleep mode I was invoking this function and I dnt know why it's not continuing it's operations. And I have many other operations like timers in my app. All these seems to be working fine, when I come back from sleep mode. So am assuming that my app is well aware that, the system has returned from sleep mode.

Anyone faced a situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your app plays audio, uses GPS, MFI etc, your app will only be able to run in the background for about 10 minutes before it terminate.

To make sure it gets its 10 minutes, you should do something like this -

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you.
        // stopped or ending the task outright.
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```

You can read more about it at [App States and Multitasking.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)